# Github - How to return the whole project to a certain commit in Webstorm

Tags: git, github, webstorm

I am using Github with Webstorm- I am the only person who is using this project.

Each time I make a significant change, I do a commit (ctrl + K on webstorm), and then I push all commits to Github every hour or so.

My questions:

1. Say I messed up in more than one file in my project and I want all files to be returned to Commit number = Last Commit - 2. How to do this?
2. Is there a way in Webstorm to automatically push to Github after every one hour? I just commit at significant points, and automate the pushing

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD~2`

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions in one post; better split them up to two posts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, just use `git reset --hard HEAD~2`, or, more generally, `git reset --hard <commit>`. Be aware that you might loose the commit on top though!